# Taylor expansion of $\lvert\sin(x)\rvert$

Tags: taylor-expansion, absolute-value, trigonometric-series

Is it possible to generate a Taylor expansion of $\lvert\sin(x)\rvert$?

I understand that this is not possible around the point $0$, since $\frac{d}{dx}\lvert\sin(x)\rvert$ is undefined at $x = n\pi$. But can we achieve this by generating the series around the points $\frac{n\pi}{2}$ and obtain an expression that is valid for all $0<x<\infty$, except the points $x=n\pi$?

Comment: Taylor series is a polynomial approximation of functions. A nice polynomial may not have so many discontinuities

Comment: I am confused by your query.  The Taylor series for $\sin x$ exists for any $x$, including $x = 0$.  Just slap absolute value signs around the entire expression and boom, you are done.

Comment: putting absolute signs around the entire expression makes it difficult to manipulate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some neighborhood of any $c \ne k\pi, k \in \Bbb Z$, either $|\sin x| = \sin x$ everywhere in the neighborhood, or $|\sin x| = -\sin x$ in the neighborhood.

All the higher derivatives of $|\sin x|$ at $c$ will therefore be the same as either $\sin x$ or its opposite, and thus the Taylor series at $c$ will either be the Taylor series for $\sin x$ or for $-\sin x$. This Taylor series will indeed converge for all $x$. But it will not converge to $|\sin x|$ everywhere.